# There is a way to add another ClientId to Google Cloud Identity Aware Proxy?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth, google-iap

I was looking for a way to add another Client Id to IAP, because if I can try to request a protected resource with a token generated with an android client id but in the same project, it gives me this error:

Invalid IAP credentials: JWT audience doesn't match this application ('aud' claim ( "the android client id used to generate the token" ) doesn't match expected value ('the IAP client ID'))

Comment: AFAIK, you can't...